Acumatica project transactions does not updated

Created a record on the Employee Time Activities form
Approved the record on the Approve Time Activities form
And then released the record using Release Time Activities form

After following above steps, It created a record on the Project Transactions form, but it does not show any details related to the original Employee Activities Record. On a doc, It says that after releasing a time activity it should create a record on the project transactions.




Above one is the created project transaction. But It's empty.

it is better to ask this question on Acumatica Community, there are many non development related forums there.
